# How to stop macbook spotlight from showing internet website and dictionary?

Tags: high-sierra, spotlight

I just want to search files in my computer. If I want to search things in internet I will go to browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: System Preferences > Spotlight... "Spotlight Suggestions" circled]

Uncheck "Spotlight Suggestions" under System Preferences > Spotlight

Farther up, there is also a "Bookmarks & History" that could be relevant.

(oh, and you might want to uncheck the "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Look up" there below)

Comment: This was replaced by "Siri Suggestions" in the later MacOS update and unchecking it does not work.